# The OSRM Demo server has moved to API Version 5

Tags: android, osmdroid

When I use RoadManager to get a road for some locations, it returns:

> The OSRM Demo server has moved to API Version 5. Documentation for the
>   new version can be found at
>   https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md

It used to work until now. How can I fix this?

Comment: osmbonuspack tells you that some of its features have moved to osmdroid. update to the latest version of osmdroid and latest version of osmbonuspack should fix your problem

Comment: @k3b thank you man. it solved the problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the warning on https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack home page.